# How to determine the SQL Server replication type by TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-replication

I want to know how to determine the SQL Server replication type by TSQL. For example, transactional replication, transactional replication with queued update, merge replication etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following query on the distribution database:

```
SELECT 
     P.Publication
    ,P.Publication_type
    ,S.Subscriber_ID
    ,S.Update_Mode
FROM MSPublications P
INNER JOIN MSSubscriptions S
    ON P.Publication_ID = S.Publication_ID
```

Publication_type - 0=Transactional, 1=Snapshot, 2=Merge

Update_mode - 0=Read only, 1=Immediate update, 2=queued update with message queue, 3=Immediate update with queued update as failover using message queue, 4=Queued update with SQL Server queue, 5=Immediate update with queued update as failover using SQL Server queue

Comment: Hi Carter, Thanks for your reply. How do you know the meaning of the column update_mode? It was not described in any version of the SQL Server documentation, even in the most recent SQL 2012.

Comment: It is documented on MSDN, but hard to find. If I can find the link again I will post it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the Microsoft BOL page with the update_mode decoded: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186785.aspx

Comment: You should explain more, not just post a link. And provide some example.

Comment: Links with little information should be posted in the comment section.

Comment: Anyway, this link is useful. Thanks all!